# Spring tool suite can not automatically show fields variable name suggest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

[image]Can not get variable name suggest in fields,but work in local variable name,how to fix it?
[image]

[image: can not assist java type]

[Java Variable type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: what version of STS (and underlying Eclipse) are you using?

Comment: if this problems stays the same after trying the answer below (about the preferences), I would recommend to report this is a bug at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS and attach a sample project that reproduces this behavior. There are so many content-assist situations and variants possible, it is hard to track this down without a simple sample project. Thanks!!!

Comment: @MartinLippert all member in my team has the same issue,you guys do not have the same issue?

Comment: @MartinLippert i upgrade to ```Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201506290652
Platform: Eclipse Mars (4.5.0)```

Comment: if this still happens with STS 3.7.0 please report a ticket to our JIRA and attach a sample project that reproduces this. Will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try restoring the default content assist options in Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced

Below is an example of what it would look like but you might have different options checked.

[image: STS content assist setting]

Select the proposal kinds contained in the 'default' content assist list:

Other Java Proposals,
SWT Template Proposals,
Template Proposals,
Type Proposals

You can try selecting java proposal(Task-Focused) or just using restore default option.