# Autocomplete in Spring tool suite 4 is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I am using STS4 and I am new to it. I did all possible ways to make work auto-complete but it's not working.
Below are the preferences setting screenshots
[image: Preference screenshot 1]
[image: Preference screenshot 1]

Instead of getting autocomplete suggestions, I am getting below pop-up window
[image: Autocomplete Pop-up]

Could anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155605/spring-tool-suite-autocomplete-content-assist-not-working-no-proposal-kinds

Comment: I forgot to hit mvn clean install command for my project. After downloading all dependencies now I am able to get suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest(sts-4.13.0.RELEASE) STS4 version
   from https://spring.io/tools
2. Open the STS4 and click "Window" -> "Preferences" -> "Java"
   -> "Editor" -> "Content Assist" and input `.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` into "Auto
   activation triggers for Java:".
3. Create a new Java project to try auto-complete.